# Celery + SQS - Using 'queue_name_prefix' writing to wrong queue

Tags: celery

Im trying to set up a Celery task using SQS as the broker. I was able to get it working using the following (minimum reproducable):

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker=f'sqs://{aws_access}:{aws_secret}@')

@app.task
def test(s):
  print(s)
```

I run this `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO`, and then call it from the shell via:

```
from tasks import test
test.delay('printme')
```

This works fine. The problem is, that I want to run this in multiple environments, so I want to designate a separate queue per environment. I found the docs for `queue_name_prefix`, which seems like what I want, but I am unable to get it to work.

What I've tried:

First I added a `config.py` file as such:

```
broker_transport_options = {
  'queue_name_prefix': 'dev-',
  'region': 'us-east-1'
}
```

and run it `celery -A tasks worker --loglevel=INFO --config=config`

this creates a `dev-celery` queue on aws, but when I try `test.delay('printme')` it doesn't execute.

I then noticed that if I went back and ran celery without the `--config` flag it ran my test task. I checked and confirmed that the `task_id` matched, so it seems that, even though I'm running celery to *read* off the `dev-celery` queue, Im still *writing* to the `celery` queue.

I've also tried using `app.conf.update` to update the celery app in code, but it doesn't seem to be working.

How can I put scheduled job on the `dev-celery` queue?

Comment: Where have you define the `queue`?

Answer (score 4):

So I did get this working, although I dont know if this is the optimal way. The problem seemed to be that the task was still being sent to the default "celery" queue, even though the worker was now listening on the "dev-celery" queue. Here's how I finally got it to work:

In the `tasks.py` code, I added a call to `conf.update`:

```
app = Celery('tasks')
app.config.update({
    'broker_url': f'sqs://{aws_access}:{aws_secret}@',
    'task_routes': {
        'test': {'queue': 'dev-celery'}
    }
})
```

and then when sending a task to the queue, using the `apply_async` method to explicitly declare the queue to use:

```
test.apply_async(
    args=['print test'],
    queue='dev-celery'
)
```

Hopefully that helps someone ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have used the below code for queue_name_prefix...
It is in Flask App running on production..

```
from celery import Celery

def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        broker="sqs://",
        broker_transport_options={
            "queue_name_prefix": "{SERVICE_ENV}-{SERVICE_NAME}-"
        },
    )
    task_base = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(task_base):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return task_base.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask

    return celery
```